# NavigationView no encontrado en android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-navigationview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da este error y no se porque estuve buscando y este es el resultado de mi gradle...

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Pero ni con lo ultimo añadido me funciona que fue lo que encontre... Alguna ayuda??? Gracias

Comment: te falta la implementacion de design y support ('com.android.support:design:26.1.0', 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar un [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView) a tu proyecto debes agregar la dependencia de diseño.

Ejemplo:

```
dependencies {
     ...
     ...
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
     ...
     ...
     }
```

**Dando <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> se puede agregar la dependencia adecuada a tu proyecto para la library de Diseño**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más información:

[NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView)

[Android Design support library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Después de agregarla simplemente sincroniza tu archivo `build.gradle` con el proyecto.