# (mixing version can lead ro runtime crashes). Found version 28.0.0,27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas colegas, estoy con el dolor de cabeza que he visto a muchos sufrir Estoy desarrollando en Android Studio 3.3.2 y llegue un día y al android studio me empezó a tirar error en la implementación de la dependencia `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

he probado subir de versión a la 28.0.0 pero me tira aun mas errores, he visto en otros casos que el error se puede dar por incompatibilidad entre las demás dependencia pero no se cual podrá ser si fuera ese mi caso, acepto sugerencias ya he probado poner la versión 26 y 28 y nada igual o peor, agregue todo lo referente a com.android.support que me salí3a en las sugerencias de las dependencias en la estructura del proyecto pensando que podría haber alguna con otra versión pero sigo igual.

El Bulder.gradle de mi proyecto es el siguiente

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }




}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            //url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
            url "https://maven.google.com/"
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

El builder.gradle de mi app es el siguiente

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    //compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.essco.seller'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        versionCode 81
        versionName '81.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/jtds-1.2.7.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.0.1-ftp.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: tienes una mezcolanza (27.1.1, 28.0.0, 28.0.3). Baja el sdk 28 Android 9.0(pie), haz click en el SDK manager (penúltimo ícono) pon compileSdkVersion 28,  targetSdkVersion 28 y las implementation en 28.0.0

Comment: gracias man ya me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes definido:

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

lo ideal es tener las dependencias de esta versión de API, puedes configurar las versiones adecuadas posicionando el puntero y mediante : <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> te mostrará la versión adecuada.

Lo debes realizar de esta forma:

[NavigationView no encontrado en android studio 3.0.1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168291/navigationview-no-encontrado-en-android-studio-3-0-1/168505#168505)